# Why doesn't a textbox stretch inside stackpanel WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, stretch

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="49*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,5,0" Text="Username:" />
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

[--Result image--](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjTT2.jpg)

Im trying to make it so that the textbox will fill the rest of the space inside the current StackPanel.
however the "Stretch" propety doesn't seem to work - why is that?

Is there a different way do it or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: A StackPanel does not resize its child elements in the direction of its Orientation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `StackPanel` always tries to achieve the minimum possible height/width, depending on orientation; therefore, `Stretch` has no effect. You might want to use a `DockPanel` instead, which allows children to stretch:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="49*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="25*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                Margin="30"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0,0,5,0"
                       Text="Username:" />
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]